# Orientating Linework in FME

Tags: fme-form

I am trying buffer 1 side of a line, which I have done using the method outlined in https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/20651/buffer-on-left-or-right-side-only.html. But I need to orientate the linework so its all in the same direction because some of the buffers are being placed on the incorrect side of the 5m contour (ie two different contour lines and the buffer outputs on different sides for both).  I have tried the orientor transformer but have had no luck.

My workflow clips the area to Councils LGA, and then filters out all linework that has an elevation of 5m.  The LineJoiner joins the linework that links together, and then the snapper snaps joins those lines that didn't touch together that are within 10m of one another (5m contour linework not that accurate and sometimes dont touch the next 5m contour line).
Length is calculated and filtered, any lengths under 1000m are put directly through to an area builder and the unfiltered go through a counter and multibuffer etc as per the https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/20651/buffer-on-left-or-right-side-only.html workflow.[image: my workflow]

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with the Orientor transformer?  It seems that that should be able to reverse lines going in the wrong direction.  You can use the OrientationExtrator transformer to determine the orientation of the lines first, then pass the incorrect ones to the Orientor to reverse them.  You can also get the general direction of the line with an AzimuthCalculator and possibly filtering out that way too.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to place the AzimuthCalculator transformer prior to the orientor transformer to get this to work.  From the image you can see that the original line work goes into the linejoiner (this dataset does not always touch each polyline), so I put through the snapper and another linejoiner to join all the linework together.  Calc the length of lines so anything under 1000m went into an area builder, anything over 1000m goes through the line orientation transformers with the Azimuthcalculator calculating the azimuth and the attributeFilter filtering whether its 0 to 180 degrees or 180 to 360 degrees.  From there it gets to the multibuffer and only one side of the line is buffered.[image]